# Struts2 JSON plugin includeProperties - not full regex support?

Tags: java, regex, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

[The documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html) for Struts2 plugin version 2.3.x says that the includeProperties parameter can be set, and behaves as follows:

> A comma-delimited list of regular expressions can be passed to the
>   JSON Result to restrict which properties will be serialized. ONLY
>   properties matching any of these regular expressions will be included
>   in the serialized output.

However, from my own testing, this doesn't appear to be the case.  At any rate, it does not seem to support full regex syntax as one might expect (i.e. the full set of expressions that would work with [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

Take a simple example where we might want to use the greedy optional quantifier ("?") with a group.  To make things concrete, this pattern: `^(items\\[\\d+\\]\\.)?userName$` does not work; it is ignored and your `includeProperties` ends up being `null`.

But if you instead just use `^items\\[\\d+\\]\\.userName$` then it works (the pattern is recognized and added).  Looking through `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil` source shows that there is a lot of custom code written to process the patterns.

It's not mentioned in the JSON plugin documentation that only a special subset of regex is supported.  What is the story on which types of expressions are supported or not supported by this plugin?

Comment: Please file a JIRA with the failing example; we'll need to take a  close look at how it breaks up the patterns against each chunk in the OGNL expression. There's no "story", rather it's just unusual to have anything other than straight-forward filtering.

Comment: (Or just ask on the S2 user list where devs more actively involved hang out.)

Comment: Thanks, I subscribed to that list.  Once I have a bit more time I'll prepare a test case and send it out.

Comment: What was the upshot?